# How to accept number with dot separator using string interpolation?

Tags: typescript, string-interpolation

How to create a function that accept number with dot separator.

For example

```
func('100.000.002.333') // pass
func('10') // pass
func('20') // pass
func('100') // pass
func('20') // pass
func('0100.000') // error
func('1000') // error
func('000.000') // error leading 0
func('100.000.') // error trailing dot
func('100.00.000') // error
func('.100.00.000') // error leading dot
```

Comment: Using regex? what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I need compile time check.

Comment: they're looking for a TypeScript type

Comment: The test cases are also confusing. Like why is `func('100.000.002.333')` pass and  `func('100.00.000')` error?

Comment: It is because each segment must be 3 number long.

Comment: According to your requirements, "number with dot separator", [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp0ABm) should be what you need. However, your test cases and expected results don't exactly line up...

Comment: The 3 number long requirement was not mentioned before. The requirement is still confusing.  

What exactly are you trying to do? What is the use case?

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOl16N) but I don't know how to make it shorter.

Comment: "Something like this" is not a clear requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAeGUIA9gQHYBMBnKQ4AJ0VwHMAaKABQ2zyJPMqqgF4oAiXgHzcAUAEgAPrCY4CxAAYASAN6UAZhDJQAggF9l9PStzrNAIR1yoAfjGnpLYgHJH1qAG0tdUwF0oALndPKAA6ULgkVFM6egFvMQD0LBlWZ1c3XwC3GDjhUEgoTG5YBGQUR2CARgAmAGYAFmCAVgA2YMc6cscBYQB6HqgBgD0bPoGoPOhCnjd+Ol5q+t45lqW+XhyJqAARRCpkIscABhdJRwqTqEcqi8cam7qbxpvmm4B2G4AOG4BOR17+ioAWhqUHwu32uAArgBbABGGiguAA9sA2ABDMjADhQADuyAAFlBDrlwNAAGKIMikAByMPhmh4iiUAFFMABjeCQ-AQFA7PbADrHASGVKSPnIEUXcXACwAbn+UBqgLB-MRdI0JPyAFlEPh8PAILS4QjGcppYZzWbwTK5PLNgB5ADWaHssjYFGoQi4YkkiWYbqOLisl2OUFGbKRZFwCLZaMIEACaPg8CROKgEQ0SZDf1ECRKqBgHTaQiSDncFKpwCN9LooWCOr1BurGnSvmD6ACqiT8eEwm5HIx0FUkNwbKxSNwUGHo5dpbdpA9VAEAAoMVQAk60AIAJQJeXCads5dnQ6HYKn47bsP9MBxwgHkdHk9ni-nw5VYI1L+OK+jW+Ee9D2Pc5fxvO8H1HY8qkva8oH-QDH2A08f1g+CIKfaCUL-cCgKOCpTzfGDRg0MhI3QpDkNAjAyFIshyKOAiLyw-oSMjdMIDRMFqCJej8JfAjmOo2jxjINFECQbj8BRXjGP4oiWJosjcMqWTCME1jNANTjsSk4AgA)
Works exactly as the code you've provided in the comment, but is much shorter and simplier

```
type Split<S extends string, P extends string = ""> =
    | S extends `${infer A}${P}${infer B}` ?
    B extends '' ? [A, B] : [A, ...Split<B, P>]
    : S extends '' ? [] : [S]

type x = Split<'.1234.56.', '.'>
//   ^?
//   type x = ["", "1234", "56", ""]

type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
// 1-3 digit number not starting with 0
type FirstNumber = `${Exclude<Digit, '0'>}${'' | Digit}${'' | Digit}`;
// 3-digit number
type MiddleNumber = `${Digit}${Digit}${Digit}`;
type Ok<S extends string> =
    | S extends '0' ? '0' // corner case: allow literal '0'
    : Split<S, '.'> extends [FirstNumber, ...MiddleNumber[]] ? S : false

declare function func<S extends string>(arg: Ok<S>): S;
```